# react native send intent openFileChooser option with http url not working

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent-chooser

I am using **react-native-send-intent** library to open image with default option but it is not working, here is my code

```
SendIntentAndroid.openFileChooser(
{
subject: "File subject",
fileUrl: "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png",
type: "image/png",
},
"Open file with:"
);
```

Any one has idea how to use this library.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Issue In The Above Code is the type Should Be `"file_mimetype"`

```
SendIntentAndroid.openFileChooser(
  {
    subject: "File subject", //optional,
    fileUrl: "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png",
    type: "file_mimetype",
  },
  "Open file with:"
);
```

The Above Code Opens Android chooser so the user can select which app will handle the file.

Once The Android Chooser Will Contain The Supported Apps Which Can Open The File